# Migrating tower servers to a rack sytem

Tags: hardware, rack

We have a small office but I'm starting to see the benefit of a rack. We have:

- Windows Server as a DC and for file hosting.
- Linux machine for the phone communications.
- DVR for the cameras (rack form factor actually).
- small switch.
- small router.
- small modem from the internet provider.

I'll like to have all the IT equipment at a rack because they're located at different spaces. So I want organization but also reduce the needed space.

I'll look to convert the windows server and the Linux server that are tower like servers to a rack style chassis. I'm guessing that 2U chassis for each one is ok.

I'm aware that [istar usa](http://www.istarusa.com/en/istarusa/) and [rosewill](https://www.rosewill.com/product-category/server-systems-components/server-chassis/) are brands that make those kind of chassis so I can simply disassemble and reassemble the servers in the new chassis.

I worry about the heat and what to look for in this kind of chassis. Also what to look for in a rack cabinet so I can make an objective decision.

There is no air conditioner at the office so I wonder if there is a rack cabinet that has some cooling features.

I'm not buying new servers that are rack ready just for budget reasons.

Comment: Most (if not ALL) rack chassis have ventilation from the bottom of the rack. The best thing is that all the servers are in a rack and in a separate room with air conditioning.

Comment: @Peppo thanks for the answer. Do you any recommendation on brand/model for a chassis?

Comment: Note: by design standard sized PC/server **tower systems will already fit  in a standard  19'' server cabinet** without any conversion (lying on their sides on shelves) - see for example: https://imgur.com/zRhXUIh  - But even when you have to place them upright,  you don't have that much equipment yet and can avoid the unnecessary DIY to convert them to rack mount housings. Doing so would only make sense if you have space constraints and need the additional density that pizza box style rack servers provide... But that's just my two cents.

Comment: @diya thanks for your comment, pretty valuable, I didn't know about that. Unfortunately this project was never made. Regards.

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment yet, so i just write it as answer.

The cabinet itself typically doesn't have cooling. The cooling (the actual fans) are located inside the individual chassis and blow air from the front to the back of the server. Cooling on the cabinet doesn't make much sense. A small air conditioned room would be perfect for the rack servers to keep the noise in you office low. Rack servers can get pretty loud because of their small form factor.

Comment: Even worse, rack servers are LOUD - better make sure they are not in a separate room, but in a separate SOUND PROOFED room. We talk hair drier loud. Per Server.

Comment: I give more importance to refrigeration. I have 7 servers in a rack and I do not need to isolate the sound. They are simply in a closed room.

Comment: @sandrogo thanks for the comment. Do you have a recommendation for a server chassis and for a rack cabinet? this seems to have cooling fans: https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B01A6JQQHU any opinion?

Comment: @yaazkal I can't recommend anything in particular but the one you found seems to be reasonable. The most important things to consider are build quality, cable management and proper ventilation.